# How to setup concurrent build in azure devops service - tfs

Tags: tfs, build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to build the code one after another in TFS. When the first build pipeline is completed, the second build pipeline should be triggered automatically

Comment: Are you using on-premise TFS or Azure DevOps Service?

Comment: I am using Azure DevOps Service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***If you are using Azure DevOps service***:

You could simply chain related builds together using **build completion triggers**.

> Add a build completion trigger to run your build upon the successful
>   completion of the triggering build. You can select any other build in
>   the same project.
>
> After you add a build completion trigger, select the triggering build.
>   If the triggering build is sourced from a Git repo, you can also
>   specify branch filters. If you want to use wildcard characters, then
>   type the branch specification (for example, features/modules/*) and
>   then press Enter.
>
> [Source Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#build-completion-triggers)

***If you are using on-premise and your TFS version do not support build completion triggers:***

There are two ways to run another build in your current build.

#### Option 1: add PowerShell task in your current build definition to [queue another build by REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build)

Assume another build id is 5, so you can add PowerShell task with the script:

```
$body = @{
definition = @{
id = 5    
}
}
$Uri = "http://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/project/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0"
$buildresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri -Body (ConvertTo-Json $body)
```

#### Option 2: install related extension in Market place

There are some extensions you can install for your VSTS account, then you can add the task to queue another build. such as [Queue Build(s) Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jb.queue-build), [Trigger New Build](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jihedmhadhbi.TriggerNewBuild), [Queue New Build](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=delegen.DelegenQueueNewBuild) etc.